# Self-referencing inside class definition

Tags: python, class, decorator, python-decorators, class-members

How do I reference class object inside class definition? Could you advice me how you would do it? Or more specifically how do you pass class object inside decorator of class method? 
Here is a simple example, I'm trying to pass second method I'm declaring to decorator of first one.

```
def decorate(w):
    def _wrap(f):
        def _call(*args, **kwargs):
            return w(f(*args, **kwargs))
        def _call
    return _wrap

class A():

    @dec(A.w)
    def f():
        return 2

    def w(f):
        return fr + 5
```

As expected exception is raised

```
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

As a result of my investigation i learned that `globals()` doesn't contain `A` key while i'm inside `decorate` or `_wrap` functions, but defined inside `_call`. So I could probably find passed method by string name (e.g `@dec('A.w')`), but in that case it is impossible to cache method search inside `_wrap` closure.

So how do you fix that? :)

Comment: The class doesn't yet exist while it's being defined.  Also, `w` doesn't exist when `f` is being defined, because `w` comes after `f` in the file.  If you move `w` first you can possibly make it work by using `@dec(w)`.

Comment: In this situation it's like being handed a complicated equation and straight away before you can touch the paper you are asked the exact answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot, because during class definition, *the class does not yet exist*.

You can apply the decorator after the class has been created:

```
class A():
    def f(self):
        return 2

    def w(self, f):
        return fr + 5 

A.f = dec(A.w)(A.f.__func__)
```

or you can swap the order of the two method definitions and refer to `w` as a local name still:

```
class A():
    def w(self, f):
        return fr + 5 

    @dec(w)
    def f(self):
        return 2
```

In both cases you are passing in a callable `A.w` that is **not** bound to an instance. No `self` will be passed in, so you need to add that yourself, in the decorator:

```
def decorate(w):
    def _wrap(f):
        def _call(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return w(self, f(*args, **kwargs))
        def _call
    return _wrap
```

If you didn't expect `w` to *be* bound (it acting as a static method instead), you could just use a normal function instead here.

Generally speaking, creating a decorator to call another method *on the same instance* is somewhat pointless; why not just call `w` from within `f`, *directly*?

```
class A():
    def f(self):
        return self.w(2)

    def w(self, f):
        return fr + 5
```